# Python errors: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str,

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I wrote down the code like this:

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange']
new_squares = []
i = squares[0]
while i=='orange':
    new_squares.append(squares[i])
    i +=1
print(new_squares)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I make it right?

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Sorry for making it messy for my 1st code post. I edited it properly

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. Here when you have assigned i to square[0], you are assigning a string to it. Again in the while loop, if the i does not get equal to orange , it should have gone to next element while you have incremented with 1. i.e 'orange'+1 . That's why you are getting the type error.

Modified code:

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange']

new_squares = []


for i in range(len(squares)):

    if squares[i]=='orange' :
            new_squares.append(squares[i])

print(new_squares)
```

Its better if we use list comprehension like below.

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange']

new_squares = [i  for i in squares if i=='orange']

print(new_squares)
```

Hope it helps.